# Rest API Cassandra ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

I have a DataStax Astra database and I have this example for how to get a user with a specific username:

```
curl --request GET \
    --url https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/${ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE}/user?where=\{"user_username":\{"$eq":"'+*username_value_here*+'"\}\}' \
    --header "x-cassandra-token: ${ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN}"
```

And because of Cassandra i don't have the option ALLOW FILTERING:

```
{"description":"Bad request: org.apache.cassandra.stargate.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING","code":400}
```

I can't find anywhere how to enable this option in curl command, so the question is how can i write this (if it's possible) or there are better alternatives. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: `ALLOW FILTERING` is most of cases is worst option

Comment: @AlexOtt what if we have a small database (9-10mil row) in a single node with not a complicated query, is it a bad idea to use `ALLOW FILTERING `?

Comment: you still need to scan through all your data, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API does not currently support `ALLOW FILTERING` but you have some other options.

- If usernames are unique in your system and you’re able to alter the data model you could make `user_username` the partition key. This will allow you to query by that column without needing filtering.
- Another option if you can’t change the data model would be to add an index on `user_username`. The index will enable you to maintain your existing access patterns while also allowing you to query by the username.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give a try with Partition Keys.